# Group Values Based on Vector and Update Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to group various values based on a predefined vector and then update a column.

**Sample Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Type = c("Windows", "Windows Server", "Cat", "Dog", "Eggs"))

it <- c("Windows", "Windows Server")
animal <- c("Cat", "Dog")
food <- c("Eggs")
```

**What I tried but failed**

```
df$Grouping <- gsub(it, "IT", df$Type)
```

> Error: Pattern > 1

**Method that works but long-winded**

Using `dplyr` mutate, I'll be able to achieve what I want but it is very long winded as I have multiple elements in a vector.

```
df %>% mutate(Grouping = ifelse(Type == "Windows", "IT", 
                                ifelse ...))
```

**Intended Output**

```
ID           Type         Grouping
1  1        Windows          IT
2  2 Windows Server          IT
3  3            Cat        Animal
4  4            Dog        Animal
5  5           Eggs        Food
```

Thanks!

Comment: Create dataframe and merge back ?

Comment: Your `gsub` is failing because you're providing a vector as the search-for expression. It will work if you do: `gsub(paste(it, collapse = "|"), "IT", c("Windows", "Windows Server", "Cat", "Dog", "Eggs"))`

Comment: @PavoDive that's really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a `list` (or a `data.frame`) for the mappings and then do a `left_join`

```
map <- list(
    it = c("Windows", "Windows Server"),
    animal = c("Cat", "Dog"),
    food = c("Eggs"))

library(dplyr)   
df %>% left_join(stack(map), by = c("Type" = "values"))
#  ID           Type    ind
#1  1        Windows     it
#2  2 Windows Server     it
#3  3            Cat animal
#4  4            Dog animal
#5  5           Eggs   food
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this works perfectly! I have a question though. Do you know why when I define my vectors outside of the list, the `stack(map)` does not seem to work? It shows me this error: `Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 0`

Comment: @Javier *"Do you know why when I define my vectors outside of the list, the `stack(map)` does not seem to work?"* I don't know what that means? Why "outside of the `list`"? You need to define a `list` with named elements. `stack` then row-stacks the entries from every `list` element in column `values` and then adds a column `ind` to indicate from which element they came.

Comment: Ah i didn't know the list has to have named elements for `stack` to work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of your predefined vectors and then check which element of the list has the items inside the `df$Type`

```
mylist = mget(c("animal", "food", "it"))
names(mylist)[max.col(t(sapply(df$Type, function(x) lapply(mylist, function(y) x %in% y))))]
#[1] "it"     "it"     "animal" "animal" "food"
```

Answer (score 0):

the question as posted doesn't make a lot of sense. Specifically, with the sample data, Its no simpler to to store the independent type vectors than to store the the type as an attribute of the initial data frame. maybe you could add some color that gives more detail about the nature of the problem.

with that said, assuming your problem is that the lookup vectors are stored in a different source and need to be loaded independently, a simple loop should suffice. (I'm using data.table, cause i don't even remember how to use a raw data.frame anymore):

```
df <- data.table(ID = 1:5, Type = c("Windows", "Windows Server", "Cat", "Dog", "Eggs"))
it <- c("Windows", "Windows Server")
animal <- c("Cat", "Dog")
food <- c("Eggs")

lookup.names <- c("it", "animal", "food")
for (z in 1:length(lookup.names) ) {
    lookup <- get(lookup.names[z]) #maybe need to do some more sophisticated load, like from a file or database
    df[Type %in% lookup, Grouping := lookup.names[z]]
}
```

Comment: Hi, the question posted is a watered down, reproducible example of my problem. A loop may not be as efficient as I'm dealing with a big data set; hence using a `left_join` as provided by the other users works better